# laravel update category some input refused to update

Tags: php, laravel, validation

hello guys I have problem in Laravel when I create category and I want to edit some inputs in this category it Redirect me to same page and not update any thing to database but when I want to edit all inputs in category or edit English and Arabic lang together it's working so why this happened here

**this is a view**

```
<form class="form" method="POST" action="/admin/categories/{{$category->route}}/update" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
{{-- @method('PATCH') --}}
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="label">
        <label for="ArabicName">{{__('admin.CategoryArabicName')}}</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ArabicName" name="ArabicName" placeholder="{{__('admin.CategoryArabicName')}}" value="{{$category->getTranslation('title','ar')}}">
        @error('ArabicName')
        <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror
    </div>
    <div class="label">
        <label for="EnglishName">{{__('admin.CategoryEnglishName')}}</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="EnglishName" name="EnglishName" placeholder="{{__('admin.CategoryEnglishName')}}" value="{{$category->getTranslation('title','en')}}">
        @error('EnglishName')
        <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="label">
        <label for="route">{{__('admin.Route')}}</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="route" name="route" placeholder="{{__('admin.Route')}}" value="{{$category->route}}">
        @error('route')
        <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror
    </div>
    <div class="label">
        <label for="upload_image">{{__('admin.UploadImage')}}</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" accept="image/*" id="upload_image" name="upload_image[]" value="{{$category->image}}" multiple>
        @error('upload_image')
        <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="{{__('admin.Update')}}">
```

**this is a route**

```
Route::group([
             'prefix' => 'admin',
        ],function () {
            Route::group([
                'prefix' => 'categories',
            ],function(){
                Route::post('/{category:route}/update',[CategoriesAdminController::class,'update']);
            });
        });
```

**this is a updateCategoryRequest**

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array<string, mixed>
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'ArabicName' => 'required|max:255',
        'EnglishName' => 'required|max:255',
        'route' => ['required', Rule::unique('categories', 'route'), 'max:255'],
        'upload_image.*' => 'required|image|max:2048',
    ];
}
public function messages()
{
return [
    'ArabicName.required' => __('validation.required'),
    'EnglishName.required' => __('validation.required'),
    'route.required' => __('validation.required'),
    'route.unique' => __('validation.unique'),
];
}
```

**this is a controller**

```
public function update(UpdateCategoryRequest $request ,Category $category)
{
    if(Category::where('title->ar', request()->ArabicName)->orWhere('title->en', request()->EnglishName)->exists()){
        return redirect()->back()->with('storeError', __('admin.NameIsAlreadyTaken'));
    }
    try {
        $attributes = $request->validated();
        Category::updateCategory($category,$attributes);
        return redirect('/admin/categories')->with('updateSuccess', __('admin.CategoryUpdatedSuccessfully'));
    }catch (\Exception $e) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

**this is a model**

```
public static function updateCategory($category,$attributes){
    $file = array();
    $Newfiles = array();
    if($file = request()->hasFile('upload_image')){
        $imageArray = explode('|',$category->image);
        foreach ($imageArray as $image) {
            Storage::disk('public')->delete($image);
        }
        foreach (request()->file('upload_image') as $file) {
            $fileName = md5(rand(100,1000)) . time() . '.' . strtolower($file->getClientOriginalExtension());
            $folderName = "categories/" . request()->EnglishName;
            $fullUrl = $folderName . '/' . $fileName;
            $file->storeAs($folderName, $fileName , 'public');
            $Newfiles[] = $fullUrl;
        }
    }
    $image = implode('|' , $Newfiles);
    $category->update([
        'image' => $image,
        'title' => ['ar' => $attributes['ArabicName'], 'en' => $attributes['EnglishName']],
        'route' => $attributes['route'],
    ]);

}
```

Notes: I use spatie/mcmara for localization

Comment: you are saying all fields are required so perhaps validation is failing?

Comment: I tried to remove require but give me same problem

Comment: are you showing your messages? you have redirects back with different keys for the messages you are returning

Comment: yes, message show where make and thing not match roles but I will give you some notes maybe can help you to Guess problem first I make title and route unique in database second when I dd($this->all())  before return in roles function in updateCategoryRequest its working well but if dd it after return it redirect me again